# Visual Studio 2010 didn't install MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I did a full install of Visual Studio 2010 Professional to work on an older application and it didn't install most of the MFC files (i.e afxwin.h). I tried repairing it. Has anyone else had this problem?

Mine is a 64-bit Windows 8 box.

Comment: As part of a consolidation process MFC and ATL were merged. As a result the MFC headers moved from their earlier locations to the *atlmfc\include* directory. If you port a solution to Visual Studio 2010 make sure to adjust the include paths. If you want to find out where your project tries to read headers from use the [/showIncludes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx) compiler switch.

Comment: There is no _altmfc\include_ directory. That's my problem. I've tried cleaning and re-installing three times. It was there the first time but I had to uninstall it because of an install order problem. Since re-installing, they are gone. That is the mystery. I would so love to switch up to VS 2012, but for this application its not yet  possible.

Comment: I see, that would rather indicate an installer problem then. I don't recall whether VS2010 provides an MSI. If so, you can get logging information by invoking msiexec.exe from the command line specifying the [/L Command Line Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988.aspx).

Comment: I wonder if my installer might be a little stale. I'll try downloading a new installer when i get a chance and I'll use msiexec.exe.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jordan any news? I seem to have had the same thing happen with VS 2012 Professional.

Comment: I was going to try a fresh install from a downloaded installer, but I haven't gotten around to that yet. I've been having coworker compile the MFC binaries on his computer.